# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, jsx

I'm having this error right after I fix a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')" using `const { id } = useParams();`.

ProductDetail.jsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const ProductDetails = ({}) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="ProductDetails">
        <div>
          <Carousel>
            {product.images && product.images.map((item, i) => (
              <img
                className='CarouselImage'
                key={item.url}
                src={item.url}
                alt={`${i} Slide`} 
              />
            ))}
          </Carousel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails
```

Console error: sorry its an img, dont know how to post it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
product.images && product.images.map((item, i) =>(
```

on this line product may be undefined.  if product is may or may not be present use product?.images?.map

Comment: It fix it, but you're right, product is not present, but it shows on redux tools, what could be the problem?

Comment: what happens in getProductDetails Action? does it fetch data from API

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that the `product` variable is undefined.

Use a null-check/guard-clause to protect it

```
product && product.images && product.images.map(.....
```

or use the Optional Chaining operator

```
product?.images?.map(.....
```

Since this `ProductDetails` component appears to be fetching the `product` data after the component mounts you'll need to guard against `product` being undefined on the initial render and any subsequent render until the `productDetails` state is populated. Here it may be preferable to conditionally render null or some loading indicator while `product` is undefined.

Example:

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="ProductDetails">
        <div>
          {product?.images
            ? (
              <Carousel>
                {product.images?.map((item, i) => (
                  <img
                    className='CarouselImage'
                    key={item.url}
                    src={item.url}
                    alt={`${i} Slide`} 
                  />
                ))}
              </Carousel>
            )
            : (
              <div>Fetching Product Details</div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```